# What does `sort -t' ' -rn +2 -3` do in this pipeline?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I have below code snippet written by someone but I don't understand what `sort -t' ' -rn +2 -3` does.

```
ps aux|tr -s ' '|cut -f1-3,11 -d' '|grep $USER|sort -t' ' -rn +2 -3|cut -f2 -d' '|head -5
```

Especially `+2` and `-3` options. I know `-r` is for reverse and `-n` is for numbers.

Comment: [deprecated syntax?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29#Columns_or_fields)

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/sort.shtml

Comment: `+2 -3` is deprecated syntax that is roughly equivalent to the more modern `-k2,3`...

Comment: Note that it is also possible to define the environment variable     `_POSIX2_VERSION=199209` when using GNU coreutils to emulate the old `sort` behavior, [as described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html). It does not explain what the code does, but allows you to use it without rewriting (or having to understand) it.

Answer (score 0):

The command does a lot of unnecessary work. You can replace it by the following command using `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -U"$USER" | sort -r | head -5
```

Btw, in order to simply understand what `sort -t' ' -rn +2 -3` means, you should follow the comment from `@1_CR` below your question.