# What does `sort +0 -1` do?

Tags: shell, sorting

I have an old script which contains a variant of `sort +0 -1`, but `man sort` in my system does not even mention the existence of these options.

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726736/what-does-sort-t-rn-2-3-do-in-this-pipeline), I was led to [the Wikipedia page for `sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29#Columns_or_fields) , which says:

> In old versions of sort, the `+1` option made the program sort using the second column of data (`+2` for the third, etc.). This is deprecated, and instead the `-k` option can be used to do the same thing.

But it does not mention what a negative argument such as `-1` is supposed to do.

Note that, in my "modern" sort (GNU coreutils 8.21), `sort +0 -1` works, while all of the following fail: 
`sort +0 +1`, `sort -0 -1`, and `sort -0 +1`.

I can even add pairs of numbers (e.g. `sort +0 -1 +2`, `sort +0 -1 +2 -3`), but from a short test case I cannot precisely infer their meaning.

**Edit**: for completeness, a nowadays invalid command such as `sort +0 +1` is equivalent to `sort -k1 -k2`.

Comment: What platform, what version of `sort`?

Comment: I would guess it means either columns indexed from the end or (and I think this more likely) inverse sort of that numbered column. But this is *entirely* a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the gnu `info` page on `sort`:

> On older systems, ‘sort’ supports an obsolete origin-zero syntax
>   ‘+POS1 [-POS2]’ for specifying sort keys.  The obsolete sequence ‘sort
>   +A.X -B.Y’ is equivalent to ‘sort -k A+1.X+1,B’ if Y is ‘0’ or absent,
>   otherwise it is equivalent to ‘sort -k A+1.X+1,B+1.Y’.

Therefore, `sort +0 -1` is equivalent to `sort -k 1,1` in newer systems.

Comment: Indeed, I had stopped looking for it after the 5th page, and trying a Regexp search for "+" was not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Marc B's answer:

[This GNU coreutils page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html) explains how to emulate the old behavior of `sort`, by defining this environment variable:

```
_POSIX2_VERSION=199209
```

With this variable, commands such as `sort +0 +1` behave as they did on older systems, avoiding the need to modify scripts (and potentially introduce bugs).